# How can I emulate script async defer src = https://someExternalCode in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, node-modules

The code provided for Google's browser/Javascript API involves a call at the end to actually pull the API code from https://apis.google.com/js/api.js

```html
         <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
           onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
           onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
         </script>
```

I can't use the provided NodeJS code from Google as they use child process calls for google-auth-library, which can't run in a browser.

How can I import this code properly in Node, without the HTML tags?

Edit - this is running on a web application so Node may be misleading, Javascript may be more appropriate. But, everything is arranged as node modules and npm build is run on server startup. I am quite novice at node/javascript/web development in general.

Comment: That script expects a window object and a DOM. You probably can't load it in Node, at least not directly.

Comment: What is higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I don't get it. "*I can't use the provided NodeJS code from Google […] which can't run in a browser.*" - that's why it is nodejs code, and you want to run it in node.js, right?

Comment: I am trying to get Google oauth to run in a browser-based javascript application without HTML involved directly.